# How to change default folder download in angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, download, angular8

I have a problem while I want to download file from server. I can download only from 192.178.1.1/assets/img/xxx.csv. How to change this path. I want like this: 192.178.1.1/CSV/xxx.csv. Tks for your help !

Comment: I receive error like this:
 Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'CSV/xxx.csv'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: CSV/xxx.csv'

Answer (score 0):

`let path = []; path = pathString.split('/'); let newPath = path[0]+'/CSV/'+path[path.length-1];`

Comment: Tks for your help. My problems has been resolved. You need save file under wwwroot and you can download with expect link :D